# Marker not displayed on Map until pan or zoom

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, fitbounds

I have only one marker to be displayed on the map. I got the marker LatLng and added to the map by extending the LatLngBounds for the marker's poistion and fit the bounds to the map. 
Here is the snippet I used,

```
             GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(divWrapper.getElement(), mapOptions);
             LatLngBounds latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.create();
             final LatLng latLngInstance = LatLng.create(((ResultModel)resultModel).getLocLat().doubleValue(), ((AssetMapViewerSiteModel)resultModel).getLocLong().doubleValue());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions.create();
                markerOptions.setPosition(latLngInstance);
                markerOptions.setTitle(((ResultModel)resultModel).getMarkerName());
               Marker marker = Marker.create(markerOptions);
                marker.setMap(map);
             latLngBounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
             map.setCenter(latLngBounds.getCenter());
             map.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
```

After the map is loaded I am  not to see the marker which was added until I pan or zoom on the map. The problem is seen in both the browser I tested Chrome and FireFox so looks like a Google Map issue.

Is there a solution or workaround for this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code

Comment: no the full thing, where you create the map and the marker, any related event listeners you have that might be affecting things, etc

Comment: I have initialized the map before this part of the code. This issue is seen only when I add only one marker to the map. If I add multiple markers it just works fine.

Comment: I can't find a `setPosition`-method in the [documentation](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.0/com/google/gwt/maps/client/overlay/MarkerOptions.html)

Comment: The link points to a javascript api. Also, wrapper for GWT is also available with the same API. [link] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)